# Unable to push to gitlab through proxy url

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, gitlab-api

I am using gitlab through a proxy, and I am unable to push to the remote repo from my local repo. I am using the following commands:

```
git remote add origin https://proxy-url/user/repo.git
git add .'''
git commit -m "Initial commit" 
git push -u origin master
```

on using the push command I receive this error message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://proxy-url/user/repo.git/': Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Any help on the matter would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy URL itself should not be part of the GitLab URL.

You should simply set/export `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` to that URL, that will be picked up by Git during the push.
You can also set the proxy in [`git config http.proxy`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy) setting.

In both cases, this proxy URL should generally be an HTTP one, not an HTTPS one:

```
export HTTP_proxy=http://proxy/url
export HTTPS_proxy=http://proxy/url
                     ^^^
                   still http, not https
```